# How to convert .ui file to .py file on Mac?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How do I convert my .ui files generated by QT Creator to .py files?

I used to convert the .ui files to .py files using a .bat file on windows:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.ui) do (
`echo %%f`

`C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\pyuic5.bat -x %%f -o %%`[`~nf.py`](https://~nf.py)
)
pause
```

I now no longer have access to a PC for the conversion (plus I'm tired of switching computers just to convert the file), so I need to be able to just convert the .ui files to .py in mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

I use the script below to automate .ui files and resources generation, it should work in any OS.

Just set `input_path` to the folder containing your ui files and `output_path` to the folder where you want the Python files to be generated:

Note that for extra security, the script will check that the .ui file start with the comment added by qtcreator: "All changes made in this file will be lost".

```
# Use this script to convert Qt Creator UI and resource files to python
import os
import subprocess

input_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'resources', 'qt')
output_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'src', 'widgets')


def check_file(file):
    if 'All changes made in this file will be lost' in open(file).read():
        return True
    return False


for f in os.listdir(input_path):
    if not os.path.isfile(f):
        pass

    file_name, extension = os.path.splitext(f)

    if extension == '.ui':
        input_file = os.path.join(input_path, f)
        output_file = os.path.join(output_path, file_name + '.py')
        if os.path.isfile(output_file):
            if not check_file(output_file):
                print('Warning: tried to overwrite a file generated outside Qt Creator. {}'.format(output_file))
                continue
        subprocess.call('pyuic5 --import-from=widgets -x {} -o {}'.format(input_file, output_file), shell=True)
    elif extension == '.qrc':
        input_file = os.path.join(input_path, f)
        output_file = os.path.join(output_path, file_name + '_rc.py')
        if os.path.isfile(output_file):
            if not check_file(output_file):
                print('Warning: tried to overwrite a file generated outside Qt Creator. {}'.format(output_file))
                continue
        subprocess.call('pyrcc5 {} -o {}'.format(input_file, output_file), shell=True)
```